# Acronym first use - footnote in glossary description

Tags: footnotes, glossaries, acronyms

I use the glossaries package and have a list of acronyms as well as a glossary. The acronyms are set to have a footnote at first use. For the glossary I use longtable format (actually I build my own style based on longtable but the following problem also occurs with the predefined style 'long').

Want I want to do is to refer to an (before unused) acronym inside the description of the glossary. Unfortunately, the footnote appears wrong. The footnote does not refer to the used acronym in the glossary description but to the last referred acronym before the glossaries.

The following example produces the error:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[table, dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[backref=page,plainpages=false,pdfpagelabels,colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[style=listgroup,footnote,acronym,toc,hyperfirst]{glossaries}

\setglossarystyle{long}
\makeglossaries

% arconyms
\newacronym{FPGA}{FPGA}{Field-Programmable Gate Array}
\newacronym{DD}{DD}{\glslink{displacement damage}{Displacement Damage}}
\newacronym{DDD}{DDD}{Displacement Damage Dose}

% glossary
\newglossaryentry{displacement damage}{
name = {Displacement Damage},
description = {Displacement damage description}
}
\newglossaryentry{displacement damage dose}{
name = {Displacement Damage Dose},
description = {\Gls{DD} dose description}
}
\newglossaryentry{interconnect}{
name = {Interconnect},
description = {The wiring resources in an \gls{FPGA}}
}

%\glsaddall
\begin{document}

page 1

\clearpage
\newpage

page 2\\
What does \gls{interconnect} mean?
\Gls{DDD}, \gls{displacement damage dose} and again \gls{DDD}.\\

\clearpage
\newpage

page 3

%\glsunsetall
\glsaddall
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype, title=Abbreviations]
\printglossary[type=main, title=Glossary]

\end{document}
```

On page 5:

[image: page 5]

You can see that both acronyms have the same footnote text and wrong hyperlink. I assume that there is a problem to have a footnote inside a longtable but I do not know how to fix it.
I can use `\glsunsetall` to suppress any footnotes but this is not what I want.

Another problem is that all glossary entries have page 3 as a reference, which is not correct. If I place `\glsaddall` before `\begin{document}`, all entries have page 1 as a reference. How can I suppress this entry produced by `\glsaddall`, e.g. some entries do not have any page reference but those used do have?

### EDIT1:

after compiling with:

```
- pdflatex
- makeglossaries
- pdflatex
```

I get two warnings:

> name{Hfootnote.3} has been referenced but does not exist, replaced by a fixed one
> name{Hfootnote.2} has been referenced but does not exist, replaced by a fixed one

Comment: (Thank you for providing a mwe!) As far as I can tell, the problem seems to stem from using `\footnote` inside a tabular-like environment. Switching to a different style (such as `list`) seems to fix the problem. I'm not sure of a workaround if you really need to use a style that uses `longtable`.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot - Thanks for your comment. As I mentioned, I build a custom glossary style with a table since I was not satisfied with the pre-defined ones. Therefore I do not want to change the style.

Comment: I realise you want to use your own style, I was just trying to point out that the problem must be related to using the footnote option specifically within the `longtable` environment. So really, I was just thinking out loud ;-) Your `hyperref` warnings may be due to a related problem of having `\footnote` within a `longtable`, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is caused by the fact that internally the footnote is using `\glslabel` to reference the entry but the definition of this command has changed by the time the footnote is processed. The simplest thing to do is to modify the style to ensure the label is expanded first, as in the modified example below:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[table, dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[backref=page,plainpages=false,pdfpagelabels,colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[style=listgroup,acronym,toc,hyperfirst]{glossaries}

\setglossarystyle{long}

\newacronymstyle{ex-footnote}%
{%
  \GlsUseAcrEntryDispStyle{footnote}%
}%
{%
  \GlsUseAcrStyleDefs{footnote}%
  \renewcommand*{\genacrfullformat}[2]{%
   \firstacronymfont{\glsentryshort{##1}}##2%
   \expandafter\footnote\expandafter{\expandafter\glsentrylong\expandafter{##1}}%
  }%
  \renewcommand*{\Genacrfullformat}[2]{%
   \firstacronymfont{\Glsentryshort{##1}}##2%
   \expandafter\footnote\expandafter{\expandafter\glsentrylong\expandafter{##1}}%
  }%
  \renewcommand*{\genplacrfullformat}[2]{%
   \firstacronymfont{\glsentryshortpl{##1}}##2%
   \expandafter\footnote\expandafter{\expandafter\glsentrylongpl\expandafter{##1}}%
  }%
  \renewcommand*{\Genplacrfullformat}[2]{%
   \firstacronymfont{\Glsentryshortpl{##1}}##2%
   \expandafter\footnote\expandafter{\expandafter\glsentrylongpl\expandafter{##1}}%
  }%
}

\setacronymstyle{ex-footnote}

\makeglossaries

% arconyms
\newacronym{FPGA}{FPGA}{Field-Programmable Gate Array}
\newacronym{DD}{DD}{\glslink{displacement damage}{Displacement Damage}}
\newacronym{DDD}{DDD}{Displacement Damage Dose}

% glossary
\newglossaryentry{displacement damage}{
name = {Displacement Damage},
description = {Displacement damage description}
}
\newglossaryentry{displacement damage dose}{
name = {Displacement Damage Dose},
description = {\Gls{DD} dose description}
}
\newglossaryentry{interconnect}{
name = {Interconnect},
description = {The wiring resources in an \gls{FPGA}}
}

\begin{document}
page 1

\clearpage
\newpage

page 2\\
What does \gls{interconnect} mean?
\Gls{DDD}, \gls{displacement damage dose} and again \gls{DDD}.\\

\clearpage
\newpage

page 3

\glsaddall

\printglossary[type=\acronymtype, title=Abbreviations]
\printglossary[type=main, title=Glossary]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This solves the first problem. Do you have any clue about the problem with `\glsaddall`?

Comment: @Paul Try `\glsaddallunused` at the end of the document.

Comment: With `\glsaddallunused` just before `\end{document}`, it works with the compilation `pdflatex - makeglossaries - pdflatex`. But if I compile with `makeglossaries - pdflatex` again, then wrong page numbers appear again.

Comment: Although your acronym stile works fine within the glossary, it somehow removed the `hyperfirst` option. In the text, the entries are not hyperlinked any more ... you have an idea why?

Comment: The hyperlink problem can be solved by adding `hyperfirst`into the list of `\GlsUseAcrEntryDispStyle`, e.g. `\GlsUseAcrEntryDispStyle{hyperfirst, footnote}`

Comment: I did a mistake. You have to put `hyperfirst` into the `GlsUseAcrStyleDefs` list, not in `GlsUseAcrEntryDispStyle`.

Comment: Unfortunately, `hyperref` doesn't seem to work with this example. If I click the `2` of `DD²` or the `3` of `FPGA³`, it always jumps to the first page instead of to the footnote. Any Idea why and how to solve this?