# Acronym long version in margin

Tags: glossaries, acronyms

I'm using the `glossaries` package to enter acronyms, in an `scrbook` document. For now, I'm using `\gls` in the text, and `\acrshort` & `\acrlong` in tables (to manually control the form).

Because I use a lot of acronyms in my thesis, I would like LaTeX, when using `\gls`, to display the long version of the acronym in the margin (right or left since it is a two side document, and with the possibility to make the text smaller), along the paragraph, except for the first time in each chapter since the long version is automatically entered in the text, and only in the `\mainmatter`.

Here is a MWE :

```
    \documentclass[chapterprefix,twoside,12pt,DIV=12]{scrbook}
    \KOMAoptions{headsepline=true, chapterprefix=true}
    \usepackage{lmodern}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[french]{babel}
    \usepackage{setspace}
    \setstretch{1.5}
    \usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}

    \usepackage[acronym,smallcaps]{glossaries}
    \makeglossaries

\newglossarystyle{long-ucdesc}{%
  \setglossarystyle{long}%
    \renewcommand{\glossentry}[2]{%
    \glsentryitem{##1}\glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}} &
    \Glossentrydesc{##1}\glspostdescription\space ##2\tabularnewline
  }%
}

\newacronym{unesco}{unesco}{United Nations Educational, Scientific and Cultural Organization}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\mainmatter
\gls{unesco} ......
\gls{unesco}
\appendix
\backmatter
\printglossary[type=acronym, style=long]\label{listofacronyms}

\end{document}
```

I have no idea where to start to do this. I see that the package `marginnote` can do something close with notes, but that's it.

EDIT: I see that some have used the package `glossaries-extra`, for instance the answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/352171/problem-with-glossaries-and-its-acronymlists-option), but I can't make it work (some functions seem deprecated).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to redefine acronym's format using `\defglsentryfmt`

```
\makeatletter  
\defglsentryfmt[acronym]{\glsgenacfmt  
\ifglsused{\glslabel}{\if@mainmatter\marginpar{{\scriptsize
\textsf{\glsentrylong{\glslabel}}}}\fi}{}}
\makeatother
```

If we need the original definition, for example in tabular like environment we need to use
`\mhacrshort` and `\mhacrshort` defined with

```
\newcommand{\mhacrshort}[1]{\acronymfont{\glsentryshort{#1}}}
\newcommand{\mhacrlong}[1]{\glsentrylong{#1}}
```

Here is a complete code that doesn't writes the long form to the margin more than one time per page.

```
\documentclass[chapterprefix,twoside,12pt,DIV=12]{scrbook}
\KOMAoptions{headsepline=true, chapterprefix=true}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage[acronym,smallcaps]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\makeatletter  
\defglsentryfmt[acronym]{\glsgenacfmt  
\ifglsused{\glslabel}{\if@mainmatter
\expandafter\ifx\csname mhused\glslabel\endcsname\relax
\expandafter\gdef\csname mhused\glslabel\endcsname{}%
\xappto\mhclearacrmargin{\global\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\let\expandafter\noexpand\csname mhused\glslabel\endcsname\relax}\marginpar{{\scriptsize
\textsf{\glsentrylong{\glslabel}}}}\fi\fi}{}}

\patchcmd\@outputpage{\botmark}{\botmark \mhclearacrmargin \gdef\mhclearacrmargin{}}{}{}{}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\mhacrshort}[1]{\acronymfont{\glsentryshort{#1}}}
\newcommand{\mhacrlong}[1]{\glsentrylong{#1}}

\newcommand{\mhclearacrmargin}{}

\newacronym{unesco}{unesco}{United Nations Educational, Scientific and Cultural Organization}
\newacronym{onu}{onu}{Organisation des Nations Unies}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\mainmatter
\chapter{test}
\section{test}
\gls{unesco} ...... \gls{onu}

\gls{onu} ... \gls{unesco}

\gls{onu} ... \gls{unesco}

\newpage

\gls{unesco} ...... \gls{onu}

\gls{onu} ... \gls{unesco}

\gls{onu} ... \gls{unesco}
\begin{table}[p]
\begin{tabular}{@{}rcl@{}}
\toprule
\textbf{Colonne 1} & \textbf{Colonne 2} & \textbf{Colonne 3} \\
\midrule
\mhacrlong{onu} & 1 & \mhacrshort{unesco} \\
\mhacrshort{onu} & 4 & \mhacrshort{unesco}  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\appendix
\backmatter
\gls{unesco}
\printglossary[type=acronym, style=long]\label{listofacronyms}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks!

Comment: it seems that a space is added after the short version on the second call of `\gls`. You can reproduce the error by inserting `test \gls{onu} and \gls{onu}. \gls{onu}.` at the beginning of the document. Thanks.

Comment: Yes Thank you. We need to type `\expandafter\gdef\csname mhused\glslabel\endcsname{}%`

Comment: Hi @touhami, do you think it would be possible to have the long version in the margin only for a particular category of acronym? Thanks!

Comment: @mhr I think yes. Sorry i was offline.

Comment: Great, should I post a new separate question about this?

Comment: @mhr yes i think so. and let me know please :-)

Comment: done ! https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/580794/acronym-long-version-in-margin-only-for-a-category