# Acronym long version in margin only for a category

Tags: glossaries, acronyms

I'm using the solution given [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/520573/acronym-long-version-in-margin/524397) to display long versions of acronyms in the margin, using the `glossaries` package. It works great, but I would like it to act like this only for the acronym of an organization, and not for others.

Here is the MWE

```
\documentclass[chapterprefix,twoside,12pt,DIV=12]{scrbook}
\KOMAoptions{headsepline=true, chapterprefix=true}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage[acronym,smallcaps]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\makeatletter  
\defglsentryfmt[acronym]{\glsgenacfmt  
\ifglsused{\glslabel}{\if@mainmatter
\expandafter\ifx\csname mhused\glslabel\endcsname\relax
\expandafter\gdef\csname mhused\glslabel\endcsname{}%
\xappto\mhclearacrmargin{\global\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\let\expandafter\noexpand\csname mhused\glslabel\endcsname\relax}\marginpar{{\scriptsize
\textsf{\glsentrylong{\glslabel}}}}\fi\fi}{}}

\patchcmd\@outputpage{\botmark}{\botmark \mhclearacrmargin \gdef\mhclearacrmargin{}}{}{}{}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\mhacrshort}[1]{\acronymfont{\glsentryshort{#1}}}
\newcommand{\mhacrlong}[1]{\glsentrylong{#1}}

\newcommand{\mhclearacrmargin}{}

\newacronym{unesco}{unesco}{United Nations Educational, Scientific and Cultural Organization}
\newacronym{onu}{onu}{Organisation des Nations Unies}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\mainmatter
\chapter{test}
\section{test}
\gls{unesco} ...... \gls{onu}

\gls{onu} ... \gls{unesco}

\gls{onu} ... \gls{unesco}

\newpage

\gls{unesco} ...... \gls{onu}

\gls{onu} ... \gls{unesco}

\gls{onu} ... \gls{unesco}
\begin{table}[p]
\begin{tabular}{@{}rcl@{}}
\toprule
\textbf{Colonne 1} & \textbf{Colonne 2} & \textbf{Colonne 3} \\
\midrule
\mhacrlong{onu} & 1 & \mhacrshort{unesco} \\
\mhacrshort{onu} & 4 & \mhacrshort{unesco}  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\appendix
\backmatter
\gls{unesco}
\printglossary[type=acronym, style=long]\label{listofacronyms}

\end{document}
```

I guess we could use the `type` option to separate the two categories of acronyms (organizations and others), but I don't know where to go from there.

Comment: Change to the `glossaries-extra` package, so you have access to the `\glsifcategory` command. Set as optional arguments `[category=show]` for UNO and `[category=shownot]` for ONU respectively. Last but not least replace the content within your `\textsf` command with `\glsifcategory{\glslabel}{show}{\glsentrylong{\glslabel}}{}`. That should work.

Comment: Thanks! It seems to work well on the MWE, I'm gonna try it on the document I'm working on. However, it seems the `smallcaps` option has no effect with `glossaries-extra`.

Comment: Hmm... perhaps you could try this -> `\setabbreviationstyle[acronym]{long-sc-short}`? Btw `glossaries-extra` recommends the use of `\newabbreviation` instead of `\newacronym`.

Comment: It returns this error: `Error: Undefined abbreviation style 'long-sc-short' \setabbrevionstyle[acronym]{long-sc-short}`

Comment: Upps ... my fault. Should have read the right package-doc ^^# (see. section **Acronym Style Modifications**, table 2.1 in doc for `glossaries-extra`). For me it works with `\setabbreviationstyle{long-short-sc}`. And to sum everything up, i will post the completed MWE as a separate answer.

Comment: It took me hours to figure out why the small caps worked on the MWE but not on my document. It turns out that if at least one acronym has no category defined, it deactivates small caps for all acronyms! Thanks for your help and full MWE, I'm marking it as resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For explanations see comment dialog below initial question.

```
\documentclass[chapterprefix,twoside,12pt,DIV=12]{scrbook}
\KOMAoptions{headsepline=true, chapterprefix=true}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}

\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries-extra}
\setabbreviationstyle{long-short-sc}
\makeglossaries

\makeatletter  
\defglsentryfmt[acronym]{\glsgenacfmt  
    \ifglsused{\glslabel}{\if@mainmatter
        \expandafter\ifx\csname mhused\glslabel\endcsname\relax
        \expandafter\gdef\csname mhused\glslabel\endcsname{}%
        \xappto\mhclearacrmargin{\global\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\let\expandafter\noexpand\csname mhused\glslabel\endcsname\relax}\marginpar{{\scriptsize
                \textsf{\glsifcategory{\glslabel}{show}{\glsentrylong{\glslabel}}{} }}}\fi\fi}{}}

\patchcmd\@outputpage{\botmark}{\botmark \mhclearacrmargin \gdef\mhclearacrmargin{}}{}{}{}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\mhacrshort}[1]{\acronymfont{\glsentryshort{#1}}}
\newcommand{\mhacrlong}[1]{\glsentrylong{#1}}
\newcommand{\mhclearacrmargin}{}

\newacronym[category=show]{unesco}{unesco}{United Nations Educational, Scientific and Cultural Organization}
\newacronym[category=shownot]{onu}{onu}{Organisation des Nations Unies}

\begin{document}
    \chapter{test}
    \gls{unesco} ...... \gls{onu}
        
    \newpage
    \gls{unesco} ...... \gls{onu}
    \printglossary[type=acronym, style=long]\label{listofacronyms}
\end{document}
```